# Updating project to stable coroutines Kotlin 1.3.0 + Coroutines 1.0.0 error

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've specified the following in my project:

Module

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.0'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.0'
  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version'
}
```

Project

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Gradle sync completes without errors, however each of my calls to

```
GlobalScope.launch {}
```

'launch' is marked with the following error:

'Unsupported [cannot use release coroutines with api version less than 1.3]'

I've invalidated and clean rebuilt - what am I missing?

**Edit

I can see where the error is generated:

kotlin/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/calls/checkers/coroutineCallChecker.kt

```
fun checkCoroutinesFeature(languageVersionSettings: LanguageVersionSettings, diagnosticHolder: DiagnosticSink, reportOn: PsiElement) {
    if (languageVersionSettings.supportsFeature(LanguageFeature.ReleaseCoroutines)) {
        if (languageVersionSettings.apiVersion < ApiVersion.KOTLIN_1_3) {
            diagnosticHolder.report(Errors.UNSUPPORTED.on(reportOn, "cannot use release coroutines with api version less than 1.3"))
        }
        return
    }
```

Comment: You may have another dependency that depends on an older version of the coroutines library.

Comment: Please make sure that you have the version 1.3.0 of the Kotlin plugin in your IDE.

Comment: yes, AS Tools>Kotlin>Configure Kotlin Plugin Update has Early Access Preview 1.3.x version 1.3.0-release-Studio3.2-1

Comment: Then try running Gradle sync again. It looks like the sync picked up an incorrect API version for your project, so the IDE isn't highlighting the code correctly.

Comment: Cleaning, building, syncing - multiple times in different orders makes no difference.

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you remove the kotlin experimental coroutines enable stuff?

Comment: @m0skit0 yup - every reference to experimental has been removed

Comment: I also don't have core, only android reference, did you try removing core?

Comment: I removed reference to core, upped kotlin version to 1.3.10 - same issue

Comment: @marstran - ran ./gradlew app:dependencies. No references to any previous versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear you m2 cache and reimport all the dependencies. That should fix the issue. Reason being, if it was working before then you had all the dependencies you needed and by clearing your cache you refetch all required libraries needed to run coroutines.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the standard library in your dependencies. The plugin inspects that to figure out what version of the api to use.

Add `"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"` as a dependency to fix your error.

Comment: This did it for me

Comment: @jchristof no it's not, double-check it

Comment: Added  implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.21' in dependency and re - building project done fixing it.

Comment: IDE gives me same error with this project - https://github.com/gintsgints/hello-ktor-api

Answer (score 4):

Right click on project name -> Maven -> Reimport.
In my case it has helped.

Comment: I don't see any Maven menu in Android Studio.

Comment: sorry, I used maven and Intelij.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me with IntelliJ 2019.2.1 + Gradle

```
File => Project Structure
```

Then from the Project Settings Dialog select `Modules` and for each Kotlin module ensure the **Language version** and the **API version** matches.  Unfortunately these settings get reset after every Gradle sync so you have to repeat the process after every Gradle sync.

[image]**.

Answer (score 0):

If you were ok before this, perhaps this is from one of your newly added dependencies. This was the case for me, I added an out-dated version of "squash" and got the very same error. After updating the "squash" to latest version everything is ok.